# How to dynamically read from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, discord

json file that looks like this

```json
{
 "997708726666547240": 456
 "1009030663636267028": 654
}
```

this is for my discord bot that does a mute command, both ids in the config.json file are different server ids with the mute role as the value. The thing is I don't want to do

```js
if (message.guild.id) { ...code }
```

for both of the servers. So is there any way I could do something like

```js
var muteRole = config.message.guild.id
```

so that it would automatically get the mute role id depending on where the command was run.

I've tried doing

```js
var muteRole = config.(`${message.guild.id}`)
```

but that didn't work. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the [square brackets syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#accessing_properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @axiac mentioned. You could use square brackets syntax like so

```
const muteRole = config[message.guild.id];
```

Comment: huge thank you to you and @axiac

Answer (score -1):

As @axiac Or u can try this

```js
const { id:muteRole } = config.message.guild
```